# smtpd_tls_auth_only exclude 127.0.0.1

Tags: postfix, tls

I configurated postfix to force uses TLS. When an external client try to send an email using this server there is not any problems. But using webmail (127.0.0.1) postfix wants TLS:

```
delivery temporarily suspended: TLS is required, but was not offered by host 127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1])
```

Which changes I need to do to master.cf?

```
smtp_use_tls = yes
smtp_tls_security_level = encrypt
smtpd_use_tls = yes
smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/postfix/ssl/xxx.key
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/postfix/ssl/xxx.crt
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1
smtpd_tls_received_header = yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_timeout = 3600s
tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${queue_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${queue_directory}/smtp_scache
```

Answer (score 4):

You could:

1. [`smtp_tls_security_level`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtp_tls_security_level) `= may`
   This will allow your server to deliver mail to hosts that don't offer TLS or hosts with bad certificates (as it would otherwise retry unencrypted).
2. [`smtpd_tls_security_level`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_tls_security_level) `= may`
   This will cause your server to offer TLS encryption to clients on any listening port.
3. `smtpd_tls_security_level = encrypt`
   This will cause your server to require TLS encryption from all client on any listening port.

For internet hosts it's common to do both 1 and 2, but you know your requirements better than I do.

Answer (score 2):

I doubt you can do that without running a second instance of postfix with smtpd_tls_auth_only set to no and then change the webmail software to send mail to that instance instead.

You might consider reconfiguring the webmail to use TLS instead if possible or to deliver mail directly locally instead of using a TCP connection.

Comment: thanks... mhmhm... can I've an example please?

Answer (score 0):

stunnel will fix this. It creates an SSL(TLS) connection to postfix:

http://www.stunnel.org/examples/

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.